# caesar cipher using ASCII returns C-cedilla

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, ascii, caesar-cipher

So I'm currently doing a caesar cipher program using the ASCII codes for the alphabet where the original text will shift 6 characters to the right but the problem is when I input the letter z, it returns Ç instead of returning the letter f. Here's my code so far:

```
void strEncrypt(string userin)
{
    char wordArray[userin.length()];
    strcpy(wordArray, userin.c_str());

    for (int i=0; i<userin.size(); i++)
    {
        if(wordArray[i]>=65 && wordArray[i]<91)
        {
            wordArray[i] = wordArray[i] + 6;
            if (wordArray[i]>90)
            {
                wordArray[i] = wordArray[i]-26;
            }
        }
        else if(wordArray[i]>=97 && wordArray[i]<123)
        {
            wordArray[i] = wordArray[i] + 6;
            while(wordArray[i]>=123)
            {
                wordArray[i] = wordArray[i]-26;
            }
        }
    cout << wordArray[i];
    }
}
```

Try to compile and run it so that you'll have a clearer picture of what my problem is

Answer (score 2):

You're suffering from signed integer overflow!

A lot of this is implementation dependent/undefined behavior, but putting that aside I'm going to explain what happened.

Your `char` type is signed, and holds values from `-128` to `127`. `'z'` has a value of `122`. When you add `6`, it *would* become `128`... if it were capable of representing that number. However, the max value is `127`, and it overflows. It wraps around and becomes `-128`.

You can put a check before the addition to make sure the character's value is low enough that you can safely increase it to avoid this problem.

---

Specifically, whether `char` is signed or unsigned depends on the implementation, `signed char` only needs to hold the values from `-127` to `127`, and signed overflow is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have an overflow, using unsigned arithmetic fixes your code:

```
unsigned char wordArray[userin.length()];
strcpy((char *) wordArray, userin.c_str());
```